# Saving a Linq to Xml file as ANSI instead of UTF-8 in C# (Ivy)

Tags: utf-8, linq-to-xml, nant, ansi, ivy

In C#, I need to create XML files for use with Ivy and NAnt, but am having difficulty in getting the right encoding in the output file.

If I use XElement's .Save("C:\foo.xml"), I get the correct *looking* file, but Ivy and/or NAnt gets upset, as the file is actually saved using UTF-8 but I actually need to save it as ANSI in order to be able to use it.

I have a bodge in place at present, which is to use .ToString() to get the text and then use a StreamWriter to write it to a file.

Ideally, I'd like to set the format during the .Save() but can't find any information on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[XDocument.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save.aspx) has a number of overloads.

Writing via a properly constructed XmlWriter allows us to choose the ASCII encoding.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse( "<foo>&#160;bar&#7800;baz</foo>" );

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create( "xelement.xml", settings )) {
    doc.Save( writer );
}
```