# Saving xml file with ASCII encoding

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, linq-to-xml, ascii

I have a program which uses OpenCV to read xml files in a C++ program. I want to change my xml files using a C# program. When I use `Save` function of `XDocument` class, I get the following error: "Invalid character in the stream"

When I checked the stream, I contained the following string:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I thought that the starting characters are because of `utf-8`, so I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253021/saving-a-linq-to-xml-file-as-ansi-instead-of-utf-8-in-c-sharp-ivy) to save my xml in `ASCII` format. Encoding of my xml file changed to ascii, but `encoding="us-ascii"` was written in the xml file. My problem is that OpenCv checks if encoding is `ASCII` and since it is written `us-ascii`, It throws exception. Is there any solution to write `ASCII` for encoding attribute in the xml saved by XDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by creating a new `Encoding` class and overriding `WebName` like this:

```
    public class NonUsAsciiEncoding : ASCIIEncoding
    {
        public override string WebName
        {
            get
            {
                return "ascii";
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateXml()
    {       
        XmlTextWriter xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter("c:\\test.xml", new NonUsAsciiEncoding());        

        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
          new XElement("Test")
        );

        xdoc.Save(xmlwriter);
        xmlwriter.Close();
    }
```