# Keeping hexadecimal characters of a xml file unchanged after save?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

How do I preserve the hexadecimal characters inside a xml file after some modification to the file using `XDocument`?
For example, this is my file before any operation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1.dtd">
<article article-type="proceedings" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:oasis="http://www.niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table">
<front>
<journal-meta>
<journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id"/>
<journal-title-group>
<journal-title>Eleventh International Conference on Correlation Optics</journal-title>
</journal-title-group>
<issn pub-type="epub">0277-786X</issn>
<publisher>
<publisher-name>SP&#x00D7;E</publisher-name>
</publisher>
</journal-meta>
<article-meta>
<article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1117/12.2053541</article-id>
<title-group>
<article-title>Macro- and microscopic spectral-polarization characteristics of the structure of normal and abnormally located chordae tendianeae of left ventricular</article-title>
</title-group>
<contrib-group>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Malyk</surname>
<given-names>Yu.Yu.</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a1"><sup>a</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="yes">
<name>
<surname>Prydij</surname>
<given-names>O.G.</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a2"><sup>b</sup></xref>
<xref ref-type="corresp" rid="cor1">&#x002A;</xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Zymnyakov</surname>
<given-names>D.A.</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a3"><sup>c</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Alonova</surname>
<given-names>M.V.</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a3"><sup>c</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Ushakova</surname>
<given-names>O.V.</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a3"><sup>c</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<aff id="a1"><label><sup>a</sup></label>Bukovinian State Medical University, 2 Theatre Sq., Chernivtsi, 58000, Ukraine</aff>
<aff id="a2"><label><sup>b</sup></label>Chernivtsi National University, 2 Kotsyubinsky Str., Chernivtsi, 58012, Ukraine</aff>
<aff id="a3"><label><sup>c</sup></label>Saratov State Technical University, Polytechnicheskaya st., 77, Saratov, 410054, Russia</aff>
</contrib-group>
</article-meta>
</front>
</article>
```

This is after using modified **Cylian**'s suggested method

```
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1.dtd"[]>
<article article-type="proceedings" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:oasis="http://www.niso.org/standards/z39-96/ns/oasis-exchange/table">
<front>
<journal-meta>
<journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id" />
<journal-title-group>
<journal-title>Eleventh International Conference on Correlation Optics</journal-title>
</journal-title-group>
<issn pub-type="epub">0277-786X</issn>
<publisher>
<publisher-name>SP&#x00D7;E</publisher-name>
</publisher>
</journal-meta>
<article-meta>
<article-id pub-id-type="doi">10.1117/12.2053541</article-id>
<title-group>
<article-title>Macro- and microscopic spectral-polarization characteristics of the structure of normal and abnormally located chordae tendianeae of left ventricular</article-title>
</title-group>
<contrib-group>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>


</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a1"><sup>a</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author" corresp="yes">
<name>


</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a2"><sup>b</sup></xref>
<xref ref-type="corresp" rid="cor1">&#x002A;</xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>


</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a3"><sup>c</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>


</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a3"><sup>c</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>


</name>
<xref ref-type="aff" rid="a3"><sup>c</sup></xref>
</contrib>
<aff id="a1"><label><sup>a</sup></label>Bukovinian State Medical University, 2 Theatre Sq., Chernivtsi, 58000, Ukraine</aff>
<aff id="a2"><label><sup>b</sup></label>Chernivtsi National University, 2 Kotsyubinsky Str., Chernivtsi, 58012, Ukraine</aff>
<aff id="a3"><label><sup>c</sup></label>Saratov State Technical University, Polytechnicheskaya st., 77, Saratov, 410054, Russia</aff>
</contrib-group>
</article-meta>
</front>
</article>
```

The program code

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var basePath = textBox1.Text;
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(basePath, "*.xml",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string fp in filesindirectory)
{
string file_content = escape_string(File.ReadAllText(fp), 0);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(file_content, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
doc.Descendants("name").Elements().Remove();
File.WriteAllText(fp, escape_string(doc.ToString(), 1).ToString());
}
MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
private static string escape_string (string input_string, int option){
switch (option)
{
case 0:
return input_string.Replace("&", "&amp;").ToString();
case 1:
return input_string.Replace("&amp;", "&").ToString();
default:
return null;

}
}
```

The line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is removed and also `<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1.dtd">` is changed to `<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD with OASIS Tables v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-journalpublishing-oasis-article1.dtd"[]>`.
Why is this happening?

Comment: First, how can anyone asnwer a question about file-saving code when you don't post that code? Second, these aren't hexadecimal characters. These are HTML encoded characters. They aren't needed if you save a file using a Unicode encoding like UTF8 or UTF16. If you don't want this, you have to change your code. Post your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving a Linq to Xml file as ANSI instead of UTF-8 in C# (Ivy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253021/saving-a-linq-to-xml-file-as-ansi-instead-of-utf-8-in-c-sharp-ivy)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos here is portion of my code `XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(item,LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
     doc2.Descendants("title").First().Value = "My XML";
     doc2.Save(item,SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);`

Comment: update the question and post the code there. Check the duplicate too, it shows how to call `.Save` with different encodings

Comment: You may find the problem occurs when the XML is loaded rather than when it is being saved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does xmltextreader convert html encoded utf8 characters to utf8 string automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308230/why-does-xmltextreader-convert-html-encoded-utf8-characters-to-utf8-string-autom)  - XDocument.Load is doing the same.

Comment: Your XML is invalid.  If I try to load it into an `XDocument` I get an error `There are multiple root elements. Line 4, position 2.`.   Can you [edit] your question to share a sample of valid XML that is causing this problem -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, do you really need to **preserve** the escaping of characters, or do you just need to **force non-ASCII characters to be escaped when writing**?  The former seems not to be possible, the latter is straightforward.

Comment: @dbc I do need to **preserve** the escaping of characters like &#xABCD;

Comment: @dbc I've updated my question with a valid xml and my code

Comment: @Don_B - then I think you are out of luck.  `XmlReader` expands then automatically, well below the level of `XDocument`.  You can prevent the old `XmlTextReader` from expanding **general** entities by setting [`EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandCharEntities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.entityhandling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but there seems to be no way not to expand character entities.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42765148) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30603856) for more.

Comment: @dbc Then how do I force non-ASCII characters to be escaped when loading/writing?

Comment: When writing, use `Encoding.ASCII` as shown in that answer to which @PanagiotisKanavos linked: [Saving a Linq to Xml file as ANSI instead of UTF-8 in C# (Ivy)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323737/3744182).

Comment: before loading the xml file...escape `&` to `&amp`...and use `xdocument.parse`, instead `load` method...

Comment: @Cylian How do I escape `&` to `&amp;` before loading the file? Can you show it with some code? It will be really helpful..

Comment: @Don_B: pls see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Minified code used for better clarity, simple console application to demonstrate the trick:

### `Program.cs`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var basePath = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(basePath, "*.xml");
                foreach (string fp in filesindirectory)
                {
                    string file_content = escape_string(File.ReadAllText(fp), 0);
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(file_content, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
                    XElement test = new XElement("path", fp.ToString());
                    doc.Root.Add(test);
                    File.WriteAllText(Path.ChangeExtension(fp, "out"), escape_string(doc.ToString(), 1).ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        private static string escape_string (string input_string, int option){
            switch (option)
            {
                case 0:
                    return input_string.Replace("&", "&amp;").ToString();
                case 1:
                    return input_string.Replace("&amp;", "&").ToString();
                default:
                    return null;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

### `test.xml`

```
<test>
<title-group>
<article-title>The coreceptor mutation CCR5&#x0394;32 influences the dynamics of HIV epidemics and is selected for by HIV</article-title>
</title-group>
<contrib-group>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Sullivan</surname>
<given-names>Amy D.</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="author-notes" rid="FN150">&#x002A;</xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Wigginton</surname>
<given-names>Janis</given-names>
</name>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Kirschner</surname>
<given-names>Denise</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="author-notes" rid="FN151">&#x2020;</xref>
</contrib>
</contrib-group>
</test>
```

### `test.out`

```
<test>
<title-group>
<article-title>The coreceptor mutation CCR5&#x0394;32 influences the dynamics of HIV epidemics and is selected for by HIV</article-title>
</title-group>
<contrib-group>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Sullivan</surname>
<given-names>Amy D.</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="author-notes" rid="FN150">&#x002A;</xref>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Wigginton</surname>
<given-names>Janis</given-names>
</name>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
<name>
<surname>Kirschner</surname>
<given-names>Denise</given-names>
</name>
<xref ref-type="author-notes" rid="FN151">&#x2020;</xref>
</contrib>
</contrib-group>
<path>C:\Users\Cylian\Documents\oo0oo\test.xml</path></test>
```

Hope this could help. (Again this is just a quick and dirty trick, better options are already there)...:)

Comment: Can you explain the line `File.WriteAllText(Path.ChangeExtension(fp, "out"), escape_string(doc.ToString(), 1).ToString());`.

Comment: write all the text to a file, same name as the input file(variable fp,  only the extension differs), and its content would be xdocument's string...but this time `&amp` changed to `&` again...

Comment: using your code I modified but my test code in the post above. But now it has a different issue. Please check the main post above.

Comment: @Don_B: now that is a different cup of tea...your initial question was not about that...and hope your initial problem had solved now...and if so, please accept this answer...and for the new problem start a fresh thread discussing your problems...happy coding... :)

Comment: How is my current question different than my initial one? In my initial question I posted a code of a xml document being modified like a node content is updated using `xDocument` and saving it and it turned UTF codes in the form `&#xABCD;` to its respective string character, so is my new code, it also modifies the file using `xDocument` but the code is much smaller for people to understand, thats the only difference....